# Wire-to-Board connector identification Sinano Kenshi Stepper STP-43D1034

Tags: identification, connector

I bought used Sinano Kenshi STP-43D1034 steppers with a connector attached the coils. Spent a few hours and wasn't able to identify the connector type. At this stage I would like to avoid changing the connector.
It does not seem to be a JST or a Molex connector. Contact's pitch is 2mm or very close to that.
Any suggestions what kind of connector that could be, would be very appreciated.

[image: Top view of the connector]
[image: Side view of the connector]
[image: Front view of the connector]

Comment: Post pictures of its mate, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I identified it with my [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN).

It's a TE, CT.

https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2&s=CT%20(crimp%204w%201r)

[2mm AMP CT Connectors](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/2mm-amp-ct-connectors.html?tab=pgp-story)

Housing: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/179228-4/1855274

[image: TE CT housing]

{Digikey}

Comment: That's exacly it. Thank you!